# try-catch doesn't catch IOException when I try to create an image file

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, try-catch

It's an image processing application. The code I show below is for creating an image file and save the fully processed `BufferedImage` to it.

```
public static void saveAnh(BufferedImage anhHoanTat) {
    String dc;
    ui.save();
    input.nextLine();
    diachiluuanh = input.nextLine();
    dc = diachiluuanh 
        + diachi.substring(diachi.lastIndexOf("\\"), diachi.lastIndexOf(".")) 
        + "_ML."+ diachi.substring(diachi.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
    File anhDaXuLy = new File(dc);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(anhHoanTat,diachi.substring(diachi.lastIndexOf(".")+1), anhDaXuLy);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ui.warningSave();
    }
    ui.hoanTat(dc);
}
```

Everything worked fine except that it didn't catch the IOException. The system showed the error, it the `FileNotFoundException`, and to my knowledge that exception is an `IOException` too.

Screenshot of what the system showed:

[image: Screenshot of what the system showed]

Then I tried to catch the exact one `catch (FileNotFoundException e)`, but then Eclipse will make me change it back to `IOException`.

Screenshot of what Eclipse prompted me:

[image: Screenshot of what Eclipse prompted me]

[image: Screenshot of what Eclipse prompted me]

*(It told me that `FileNotFoundException` was already caught by `IOException`, so eventually I had to delete it which pretty much go back to where I started.)*

Note: I added `NullPointerException` after that and the code caught it, but still didn't catch the `IOException` `catch (NullPointerException | IOException e)`

Screenshot of what the system showed:

[image: Screenshot of what the system showed]

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that you catch the exception correctly, you print it (I assume that's what you do on your `ui.warningSave();` method), but then you don't stop your method (either return, exit, throw exception) so the program reaches the last line, after the catch (`ui.hoanTat(dc);`)

The compilation errors eclipse showed you:

since `ImageIO.write()` throws `IOException`, you can't catch only `FileNotFoundException`, as it does not cover all cases.

Also, writing `catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e)` is also wrong, as the FileNotFoundException is redundant - it's already covered by IOException as it extends it.